# Mongodb java client fails when Primary Server node changes in replicaset

Tags: java, mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

**Problem:** MongoDB writes fail with the error -

> Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
>   PrimaryServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is
>   {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=intdb01:27017,
>   type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=0.7 ms, state=CONNECTED}]

This happens when the primary has switched from **intdb01** to **intdb02**.
Looks like the client driver is still looking for *intdb01*
to be primary node.

**Our Setup**

We have 3 mongoDb nodes in a replicaSet called rs0.
When we connect to it using Java, we give all 3 servers in the connection string as follows:
*mongodb://intdb01:27017,intdb02:27017,intdb03:27017/?replicaSet=rs0*

**db.version** --> 3.0.4

**Java Driver Version**: mongodb-driver-3.0.4.jar, mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar

Client Connection code:

```
if( mongoClient == null) {
    MongoClientURI mcu = new MongoClientURI(mongoConnect);
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(mcu);
}
```

mongoConnect contains the connection string shown above.

**Mongo Replicaset Status Info**

```
> rs.status()
{
  "set" : "rs0",
  "date" : ISODate("2016-07-19T21:14:03.001Z"),
  "myState" : 1,
  "members" : [{
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "intdb01",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 439786,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1468521291, 5),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-14T18:34:51Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-07-19T21:14:01.877Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-07-19T21:14:01.611Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "configVersion" : 4
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "intdb02:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 2948844,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1468521291, 5),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-14T18:34:51Z"),
        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1468523057, 1),
        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-07-14T19:04:17Z"),
        "configVersion" : 4,
        "self" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "intdb03:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 439779,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1468521291, 5),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-14T18:34:51Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-07-19T21:14:01.294Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-07-19T21:14:01.294Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "configVersion" : 4
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

I have checked and rechecked the code/config with the documentation but cannot find what is amiss.
We can simulate this by stepping down the primary. 
The Secondary takes over but the app writes start failing. :-(

Any pointers/tips much appreciated!

Adding Stack trace-

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=intdb01:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=0.7 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:370)
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:175)
at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:141)
at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:747)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:730)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:482)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.update(MongoCollectionImpl.java:474)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:325)
at com.grid.core.persistence.mongodb.dao.GridEventDao.save(GridEventDao.java:69)
... 6 more
2016-07-19 17:05:01,882 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO   org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by PrimaryServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=intdb01:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=724681, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=intdb01:27017, hosts=[intdb01:27017, intdb02:27017], passives=[intdb03:27017], arbiters=[], primary='intdb02:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

I am trying to figure out if it is a coding error or configuration. 
The last info Message in the stack trace, says connectionMode is SINGLE. Have a suspicion that it is causing this issue but I cannot find any info about it in the developer documentation site.

Comment: If you are going to down-vote a question, be man enough to write your concern to help make it better. Same applies to the person voting to close.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace please.

Comment: added stack trace of write failure.

Comment: So when intdb02:27017 is primary, is it able to connect? e.g. are you only getting these failures during the failover?

Comment: no, it keeps failing. If I change the connection string in my program and move intdb02 to the front of the string it starts working. So it appears to recognize only the first server.

Answer (score 0):

All of the server addresses should appear in the error message. For example, try this with 3 arbitrary hostnames what won't resolve:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=xxx:27117, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: xxx}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx}}, {address=xxx:27118, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: xxx}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx}}, {address=xxx:27119, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: xxx}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:370)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:58)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:747)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:730)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:327)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:323)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:314)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:250)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:187)
    at InsertTest2.main(InsertTest2.java:26)
```

Notice how all 3 server addresses appear. I would suggest that you create a simple test program like this and verify, then work backwards from there. Also verify that the hostnames resolve correctly, you might also try IP addresses.

Comment: I will try it. - create a simple test and go from there.
It is not a Host/IP resolution as I can connect independently to all , just not when the secondary becomes the primary. I suspect something in the way i have my connection string. I will play around and update if I make any headway.
Last option is to download the source if  I can find it for org.mongodb.driver.cluster.